# How do I set up a headless server via VNC?

Tags: 11.04, monitor, headless

I'm trying to configure my system to run headless and access the desktop via VNC when necessary. It seems everytime I unplug the monitor while ubuntu is running, the system freezes and I am forced to do a hard shut down.

If I start the computer up without a monitor it won't boot up all the way and I am still unable to access the desktop through VNC. I am able to VNC to it while there is a monitor attached to it. Automatic login is enabled. I want to VNC into my ubuntu machine without a monitor.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/136785/67952

Comment: Joe, Would you mind posting the content of xorg.conf after you ran the command: sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg . Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is a fairly common question. However, I personally believe that VNC is a poor solution for this kind of usage. I would recommend having a look at X2Go. It is much, much, faster tha VNC and it forwards audio using PulseAudio, etc, over SSH. It is quite easy to setup and you don't need to be logged in on the server for it to work.

Have a look at http://www.x2go.org/doku.php/start

Comment: I'll definitely give that a try, but that didn't help my monitor situation, however, I did happen to stumble across a solution that worked for me. I ran this command: sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg and now I am able to run that machine without a monitor/keyboard/mouse. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

OP has resolved the issue and posted the answer as a comment;

> I did happen to stumble across a solution that worked for me. I ran
>   this command: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` and now I am able
>   to run that machine without a monitor/keyboard/mouse

Comment: can anyone else verify that this works and possible give a brief explanation on why?