# Run Ubuntu without monitor? Want to remote it with RealVNC

Tags: monitor, vnc

Friends,

I am totally new to Ubuntu but I want to use it on an old computer of mine to run Plex Media Server to stream movies to my Chromecast. I have managed to install everything and it was all working fine during my testings. I am going to place the server in my basement and I want to remote control it by using RealVNC. I have installed it on both my Ubuntu machine and my regular laptop running Windows 8. It's was all working smooth, until I disconnected the monitor from the Ubuntu machine. Seems like Ubuntu want a monitor connected!

I have googled around and tried some tips with editing the xorg.conf file. Without success.

Somebody help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set up a headless server via VNC?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60474/how-do-i-set-up-a-headless-server-via-vnc)

Comment: Also search "ubuntu headless"

Comment: I am using VNC viewer with vnc server setup in a ubuntu server, no monitor at all .. multiples users are using same server without a monitor plugged in to server it self.. just like RDP , vnc can be used http://askubuntu.com/questions/581979/ubuntu-14-10-multiple-simultaneous-independent-remote-desktop-like-connection